# Prevent VS Code from jumping to cursor when switching tabs

Tags: visual-studio-code, scroll

- I set my cursor to the middle of a file
- scroll to the bottom of the file (but not click)
- move to 2nd tab
- move back to 1st tab
- now it jumps to the cursor (middle), not to last position (bottom)

How can I make it not to jump to cursor on tab change?

(explorer.autoReveal is not relevant here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code does not do this normally. This was found by [extension bisect](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to be caused by the [ietxaniz.fold-ninja](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ietxaniz.fold-ninja) extension. I'd suggest that you raise a bug ticket on [its issue tracker](https://github.com/ietxaniz/vscode-fold-ninja/issues). In the meantime, consider disabling the extension.